# how to insert imageview to custom xml shape

Tags: android

i want to display imageview inside custom shape that created using drawer xml file in android. Iv'e searched the internet for weeks with no results. The only answers i find is using regular shapes (circle, rectangle) or using xml in layers (put the image as background) but the image is dynamic from server.

This is the image view

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/upload_newdish_icon"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dish_name_et"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
```

And this is the custom shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:width="70dp" android:height="70dp" android:viewportHeight="700.000000" android:viewportWidth="700.000000">

<group android:scaleX="0.100000" android:scaleY="-0.100000" android:translateY="700.000000">
<path android:fillColor="@color/colorPrimary" android:pathData="M3065 6779 c-632 -31 -1270 -127 -1895 -285 -274 -70 -351 -105 -455 -209 -104 -104 -139 -181 -209 -455 -145 -574 -232 -1117 -278 -1745 -19 -256 -16 -979 6 -1245 46 -580 135 -1128 271 -1665 71 -280 105 -355 210 -460 104 -104 181 -139 455 -209 544 -137 1088 -226 1670 -273 301 -24 1019 -24 1320 0 582 47 1126 136 1670 273 274 70 351 105 455 209 104 104 139 181 209 455 145 574 232 1117 278 1745 19 256 16 979 -6 1245 -46 580 -135 1128 -271 1665 -71 280 -105 355-210 460 -104 104 -181 139 -455 209 -914 231 -1864 329 -2765 285z"/>
</group>
</vector>
```

Comment: add some code what you did so far?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve this issue is to use a FrameLayout which contain two elements : your custom shape and relativelayout containing the imageview

```
<FrameLayout>

<Custom_shape
android:layout_width="xdp"
android:layout_height="ydp"
>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="xdp"
android:layout_height="ydp">

<imageview
centerinparent="true"
//dimension of the image view (should <(x,y) )
//or set wrap content for the widh and the height + set a padding to get the imageview in the center of relativelayout

>

</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Custom shape and RelativeLayout should have the same dimensions (width and height)

Comment: Hello @Karim thanks for reply, What the meaning of <Custom_shape...?

Comment: It represent your custom shape in xml.